# upload value to php in vue with POST

Tags: php, json, ajax, post

I have the following function component in vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="configurations">
  <h4>Select your input files!</h4>
  <form  enctype="multipart/form-data" @submit.prevent="submitForm" align="left" id="imageForm">
    <input v-model="inputTable.topic" name="topic" debounce="500"> {{inputTable.topic}} <br>
    <input v-model="inputTable.name" name="name" debounce="500"> {{inputTable.name}} <br>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
export default {
  data() {
    return{
      inputTable: {
        topic: '',
        name: ''
    }}},

  methods: {
    submitForm: function() {
      var data = this.inputTable
      this.$http.post('/api/santander/php/updatedata.php', data).then(function(response) {
          //this.updated = true;
        })
  }}}
</script>
```

Now I try to mobtain the values in PHP, but I dont know how. I tried this:

```
$request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))
$field = $request.name;
$name = $request.field;
```

But that did not work. Is there any good way to do this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: PHP uses the `->` for its object operator, try `$request->name` and `$request->topic`

Answer (score 0):

Try dumping the `$_POST` contents to see if your variables are passed in correctly. Like this:

```
class updatedate {
    public function index {
        var_dump($_POST);
    }
}
```

This should dump both: `$_POST['topic']` and `$_POST['name']`